# Mercurial cat command using --include

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Using version 4.1.1 of Mercurial, I would like to provide a file specifying a bunch of files as args to an `hg cat` command, so that each file is output to a different file.  I thought the following would work:

```
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst
```

where files.lst looks like this

```
foo01.txt
foo02.txt
```

But it yields an error message saying "invalid arguments" plus a usage message.

Here is an MWE that sets up a code repository with the required structure and then tries running the `cat` command shown above.

```
hg init mwe
cd mwe
echo abc > foo01.txt
echo def > foo02.txt
echo PQR > baz.txt
echo files.lst > .hgignore
hg add .hgignore
hg add foo*.txt
hg add baz.txt
echo foo01.txt >> files.lst
echo foo02.txt >> files.lst
hg ci -m "Adding all files"
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' baz.txt
cat catOut-baz.txt
rm catOut*
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst baz.txt
cat catOut-baz.txt
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst
```

Here is a trace of these commands and their results as typed to a shell:

```
~/tmp $ hg init mwe
~/tmp $ cd mwe
~/tmp/mwe $ echo abc > foo01.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ echo def > foo02.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ echo PQR > baz.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ echo files.lst > .hgignore
~/tmp/mwe $ hg add .hgignore
~/tmp/mwe $ hg add foo*.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ hg add baz.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ echo foo01.txt >> files.lst
~/tmp/mwe $ echo foo02.txt >> files.lst
~/tmp/mwe $ hg ci -m "Adding all files"
~/tmp/mwe $ hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' baz.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ cat catOut-baz.txt
cat catOut-baz.txt
PQR
~/tmp/mwe $ rm catOut*
rm catOut*
~/tmp/mwe $ hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst baz.txt
~/tmp/mwe $ cat catOut-baz.txt
cat: catOut-baz.txt: No such file or directory
~/tmp/mwe $ hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst 
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst 
hg cat: invalid arguments
hg cat [OPTION]... FILE...

output the current or given revision of files

options ([+] can be repeated):

 -o --output FORMAT       print output to file with formatted name
 -r --rev REV             print the given revision
--decode              apply any matching decode filter
 -I --include PATTERN [+] include names matching the given patterns
 -X --exclude PATTERN [+] exclude names matching the given patterns

(use 'hg cat -h' to show more help)
~/tmp/mwe $
```

You have to supply a file argument to avoid the error message.  But that argument is ignored if an --include and an -o are supplied.

I suspect no one has ever used the `--include` argument to `cat` before, because there is a dearth of explanation out there about how `--include` arguments are handled.  Either that or I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to supply a file argument to avoid the error message. But that argument is ignored if an `--include` and an `-o` are supplied.

It is not literally *ignored*.  The problem is that `--include` means something odd.

> ... because there is a dearth of explanation out there about how `--include` arguments are handled.

That does seem to be the case!  There is a description in `hg help patterns` but it is rather inadequate (in my opinion at least).  What `--include` means is that *only* files matching the patterns in the file are used.  Think of this as "include only", rather than "also include".

Thus, if your listfile has those two file names in it, you may run, e.g.:

```
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst baz.txt foo01.txt
```

and Mercurial will extract `foo01.txt` since it's in the list.

You might think you could use:

```
hg cat -o 'catOut-%s' --include listfile:files.lst '*'
```

but you can't (well, you can on Windows, as hg does glob style matching there, but that's the wrong approach).  The right trick is to direct `hg cat` to read a *directory*, namely the top level directory of the repository:

```
hg cat .
```

(though there are similar methods, such as using `set:*`; see `hg help filesets`).  Then the filtering produced by `--include` strips you down to just the files you want included.

#### More "color", as they say in some circles - no need to read this!

(This is just side stuff I found while researching this answer a bit.  I wondered how one made `hg cat` scan every file in a revision, so I plunged into the source.)

For reference, here is the snippet of Python code that implements `hg cat`:

```
@command('cat',
    [('o', 'output', '',
     _('print output to file with formatted name'), _('FORMAT')),
    ('r', 'rev', '', _('print the given revision'), _('REV')),
    ('', 'decode', None, _('apply any matching decode filter')),
    ] + walkopts,
    _('[OPTION]... FILE...'),
    inferrepo=True)
def cat(ui, repo, file1, *pats, **opts):
    """output the current or given revision of files

    Print the specified files as they were at the given revision. If
    no revision is given, the parent of the working directory is used.

    Output may be to a file, in which case the name of the file is
    given using a format string. The formatting rules as follows:

    :``%%``: literal "%" character
    :``%s``: basename of file being printed
    :``%d``: dirname of file being printed, or '.' if in repository root
    :``%p``: root-relative path name of file being printed
    :``%H``: changeset hash (40 hexadecimal digits)
    :``%R``: changeset revision number
    :``%h``: short-form changeset hash (12 hexadecimal digits)
    :``%r``: zero-padded changeset revision number
    :``%b``: basename of the exporting repository

    Returns 0 on success.
    """
    ctx = scmutil.revsingle(repo, opts.get('rev'))
    m = scmutil.match(ctx, (file1,) + pats, opts)

    ui.pager('cat')
    return cmdutil.cat(ui, repo, ctx, m, '', **opts)
```

The most critical line is:

```
def cat(ui, repo, file1, *pats, **opts):
```

This means that non-option `FILE...` arguments (as in the description just before the `def`) are bound with the first one going to `file1` and the rest going to `*pats` (as a Python tuple).  This forces you to pass one or more file-name or file-set arguments.

Those file name arguments (`baz.txt` or whatever) are passed in to `scmutil.match`, which is what is going to find the files in the manifest for the specified revision—the one now in `ctx`, obtained by the previous line calling `scmutil.revsingle`, which gets the last revision in the `--rev` option, defaulting to the current revision (the first parent of the working directory).

It's `scmutil.match` that handles the `--include` option.  Unfortunately this code is rather impenetrable:

```
m = ctx.match(pats, opts.get('include'), opts.get('exclude'),
              default, listsubrepos=opts.get('subrepos'), badfn=badfn)
```

(with `pats` being the non-empty file names passed in as command line arguments), which invokes this code in `context.py`:

```
def match(self, pats=None, include=None, exclude=None, default='glob',
          listsubrepos=False, badfn=None):
    if pats is None:
        pats = []
    r = self._repo
    return matchmod.match(r.root, r.getcwd(), pats,
                          include, exclude, default,
                          auditor=r.nofsauditor, ctx=self,
                          listsubrepos=listsubrepos, badfn=badfn)
```

which gets us into `match.py`'s `class match` object, which is what implements the `listfile:` part.  Here's a bit from that:

```
    matchfns = []
    if include:
        kindpats = self._normalize(include, 'glob', root, cwd, auditor)
        self.includepat, im = _buildmatch(ctx, kindpats, '(?:/|$)',
                                          listsubrepos, root)
        roots, dirs = _rootsanddirs(kindpats)
        self._includeroots.update(roots)
        self._includedirs.update(dirs)
        matchfns.append(im)
```

and `self._normalize` winds up reading the file given as the `listfile` argument, so that's what is in `kindpats`.  (The string literal passed to `_buildmatch` is a regular expression glob suffix pattern, i.e., file names from the include file are followed by an implied trailing slash or end-of-string.)